# Disable package without uninstalling

Tags: package

I installed package from `M-x package-list-packages` and want to disable this package without uninstalling.

**UPDATE** With `(setq package-load-list '((company nil)))` I have in `*Packages*` buffer:

```
company            0.9.3         disabled              Modular text completion framework
```

but completion dialog still appear.

I have

```
(defun my-company-prog-mode-setup ()
  (setq-local company-dabbrev-code-other-buffers 'code)
  (setq-local company-backends '((company-capf company-dabbrev-code company-files)))
  (company-mode 1))

(when (featurep 'company)
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-company-prog-mode-setup))
```

Answer (score 7):

One of the many great things about [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) is that it lets you [disable](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#conditional-loading) specific packages with a simple keyword (viz. `:disabled t`).

Comment: This only disables the `use-package` configuration, not package.el's initialization.

Answer (score 5):

You can control which packages are loaded through the variable `package-load-list`. Set it in your init file, before calling `package-initialize` if you do this explicitly. You can reach it from the Customize interface (“Package” → “Package Load List”).

`package-load-list` is an list whose elements are lists whose first element is a package name (as a symbol). The second element of the list can be a string to force a specific version of the package to be loaded, `t` to load the latest version, or `nil` to disable the loading of the package. Also put `all` in the list, so that Emacs will load the latest version of packages which are not explicitly mentioned.

```
(setq package-load-list '(all
                          (unwanted-package nil)
                          ))
```

Comment: Hm... `(setq package-load-list '((company nil)))` doesn't work for me. Seems it's better to uninstall. At least this can be done in visual way because finding package name can be cumbersome.

Comment: @gavenkoa Works for me under Emacs 24.4. `company-mode` is not autoloaded. I forgot to mention that you should put `all` in the list, without it all your packages would have been disabled. Check that you're setting this before any call to `package-initialize` or anything that would call `package-initialize`, such as `use-package` (but if you're using `use-package`, see [mclear's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32460)).

Comment: @gavenkoa Did you also restart Emacs? This doesn't unload the package after the fact.